# Why fetched data is not stored in global variable so that I can use it outside of async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await, fetch-api

So, I want to use fetched data from an API in my app, but I cannot store the fetched data outside of async function getapi(), but if I use all other functions while staying inside that getapi() function, they are working fine but I want to store the fetched data outside of that function to make my code more readable and clear.

```
var mdata;
const api_url = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/602998b0f460fe73a1967fe0";
async function getapi(url) {

    const response = await fetch(url);
    data = await response.json();
    mdata = data;

}
getapi(api_url);
console.log(mdata);
```

[image: Output of this JS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the way you're executing your code you're not waiting for the async function to finish.

Your code should look something like this.

Learn more about promises here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
var mdata;
const api_url = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/602998b0f460fe73a1967fe0";
async function getapi(url) {

    const response = await fetch(url);
    data = await response.json();
    mdata = data;

}
getapi(api_url).then( function(){
  console.log(mdata);
  }
);
```

Comment: No, I think you didn't got my point, I want to store the fetched data in my mdata variable which is a global variable and I want to use pass mdata variable(fetched data) to some other function to do some work like access data.